# I am looking for best way to handle duplicate Strings in Java Application for Heap Memory?

Tags: java

I was analyzing the heap dump of my application and found there are lots of duplicate strings in the heap. I am looking for a way to minimize the memory consumed by the duplicated strings.

Below is the list of the String objects with their count in the heap.

```
Duplicate String Percentage Wasted Count
"java.lang.Throwable\n at
org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getLocationInformation(LoggingEvent.java:247)\n
at org.apache.log4j ...[length 4460]"
1.25mb 147
"java.lang.Throwable\n at
org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getLocationInformation(LoggingEvent.java:247)\n
at org.apache.log4j ...[length 10742]"
861.96kb 42
"java.lang.Throwable\n at
org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getLocationInformation(LoggingEvent.java:247)\n
at org.apache.log4j ...[length 10744]"
861.96kb 42
"file" 610.99kb 19,495
"java.lang.Throwable\n at
org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getLocationInformation(LoggingEvent.java:247)\n
at org.apache.log4j ...[length 4493]"
608.6kb 70
```

Comment: Please refer http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/

Answer (score 4):

Switch to G1GC as from JDK 8u20 it has string deduplication feature (see [JEP 192: String Deduplication in G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/192)).

To further reduce memory consumption starting from JDK 9 ISO-8859-1/Latin-1 strings can be internally compacted to bytes (see [JEP 254: Compact Strings](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)).